# What is the difference in meaning and usage between "content" and "program"?

Tags: word-usage

I am writing my resume and would like to describe a job in which I planned what films to stream on a VOD service in one short phrase.

Which one of the following is most appropriate?

Planning content
Planning program
content planning
program planning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I believe all are basically equivalent, here are the slight nuisances of how one might read each of them:

Planning content - *the act of preparing what content or material would be shown*
Planning program - *a software program that assists the user with planning events or calendar items*
Content planning - *planning what content or material to present, also implies that such planning is available as a feature of a product*
Program planning - *preparing a program's items or events.  This also has an alternate definition of making a design for a piece of software.*

If forced to choose one over the other, I'd probably go with planning content, or content planning - depending on the context in which it is used.

Comment: Is 'nuisances' intended here, or a malapropism?

Comment: Malapropism.  Props for pointing that out.  :P